# Best way to create shared index between two data sets in Xarray?

Tags: python-xarray

I have an ordered list of lat, lons and I want to reorder the index of a gridded climate data set to line up with this ordered list.

I am currently using `DataSet.sel_points()` in Xarray. It is taking around 13 minutes to complete. Is this the expected time it should take for this operation?

My netcdf file is ~750M.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g., with code and printing a preview of your input datasets.